# Inserir array em um banco de dados usando PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados, array

No site que estou criando eu tenho um formulário onde as pessoas podem adicionar vários tópicos. O meu problema está no momento onde é criado um segundo ou mais tópicos pois só o primeiro vai para o banco e eu não consigo fazer os demais serem inseridos.

O código que eu to fazendo é esse aqui:

```
<div class="input-field col s10 ">
<input id="topico" type="text" name="campo[]" class="validate" required  >
<label for="topico" class="black-text text-black">Adicione pelo menos um tópico</label>
</div>
<!--BOTAO PARA ADICIONAR MAIS TOPICOS -->
    <a class="btn-floating btn- green" onClick="addCampos()" >
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </a>
    </div>  
    <!--SCRIPT PARA ADIÇÃO DE TOPICOS DE REUNIAO-->
    <script>
      var qtdeCampos = 1;
      function addCampos() {
        var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
//Criando o elemento DIV;
var objFilho = document.createElement("div");
//Definindo atributos ao objFilho:
objFilho.setAttribute("id","filho"+qtdeCampos);

//Inserindo o elemento no pai:
objPai.appendChild(objFilho);
//Escrevendo algo no filho recém-criado:
document.getElementById("filho"+qtdeCampos).innerHTML = "<table><tr><td><div align='right'><input type='text' id='curso"+qtdeCampos+
"' name='campo[]'></div></td> <td><div align='left'<a class='btn-floating btn- light red' onclick='removerCampo("+qtdeCampos+")' value='Apagar campo'><i class='material-icons'>remove</i></a></div></td></tr></table></div></div>";
qtdeCampos++;
}

function removerCampo(id) {
var objPai = document.getElementById("campoPai");
var objFilho = document.getElementById("filho"+id);

//Removendo o DIV com id específico do nó-pai:
var removido = objPai.removeChild(objFilho);
}
</script>

<div id="campoPai"></div>
```

O PHP:

```
$nm_reuniao = $_POST['nm_reuniao'];
$dt_reuniao = $_POST['dt_reuniao'];
$nm_topico = $_POST['campo[]'];
$query = "INSERT INTO reuniao (nm_reuniao,dt_reuniao,nm_criador) VALUES ('$nm_reuniao','$dt_reuniao', '$logado')";

$insert = mysql_query($query,$connect);

if($insert){
  echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Reuniao cadastrado com sucesso!');window.location.href='pagina site.php'</script>";
}else{
  echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Não foi possível cadastrar esse usuário');window.location.href='pagina site.php'</script>";
}
```

Comment: Caso alguma resposta solucione seu problema marque-a como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079.

Answer (score 2):

Os problemas encontrados no seu código são:

1. Errado `$nm_topico = $_POST['campo[]'];`

   Correto `$nm_topico = $_POST['campo'];`
2. Os values da declaração INSERT  `('$nm_reuniao','$dt_reuniao', '$logado')"`;

   Ao invés de `$logado` acho que deveria ser `$nm_topico`
3. Mas mesmo sendo `$nm_topico` iria inserir somente uma linha na tabela

**Esqueça essas correções que a solução proposta não vai utilizá-las.**

> Uma única declaração `INSERT ... VALUES` pode adicionar múltiplos registros em uma tabela se você fornecer múltiplas listas de valores. Para fazer isso, forneça uma lista de valores entre parêntesis para cada registro e separe as listas com virgulas.

Por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO PESSOAS (nome, sobrenome)
VALUES ('Paula','Cavalcante'),('Leo','Caracciolo'),('dvd','SemSobrenome')
```

A declaração mostrada cria três registros na tabela pessoas, atribuindo às colunas `nome` e `sobrenome` de cada registro os valores listados. A coluna `id` não é listada explicitamente, de modo que o MySQL atribui um valor da sequência para essa coluna em cada registro.

Uma declaração INSERT de múltiplas linhas é logicamente equivalente a um conjunto de declarações de única linha individuais. Entretanto, a declaração de múltiplas linhas é mais eficiente porque o servidor pode processar todas as linhas de uma vez em vez de em operações separadas. Quando você tiver muitos registros a adicionar, **declarações de múltiplas linhas fornecem um desempenho melhor e reduzem a carga do servidor**. Por outro lado, tais declarações são mais prováveis de alcançar o tamanho máximo do buffer de comunicação usado para transmitir informações para o servidor (esse tamanho é controlado pela variável `max_allowed_packet`, que possui um valor padrão de 1MB).

Código PHP

```
$nm_reuniao = $_POST['nm_reuniao'];
$dt_reuniao = $_POST['dt_reuniao'];

//Use o foreach para gerar a lista de valores
foreach($_POST['campo'] AS $indice => $valor) {
  $values .= " ('$nm_reuniao', '$dt_reuniao', '$valor'),";
}
//retira a ultima virgula
$values=substr($values, 0, -1);

$query = "INSERT INTO reuniao (nm_reuniao,dt_reuniao,nm_criador`) VALUES $values";

$insert = mysql_query($query,$connect);
```

> ### Talvez fosse como abaixo indicado, não sei, sua pergunta não está bastante clara

```
$values .= " ('$nm_reuniao', '$dt_reuniao','$logado','$valor'),";

$values=substr($values, 0, -1);

$query = "INSERT INTO reuniao (nm_reuniao,dt_reuniao,nm_criador,nm_topico) VALUES $values";
```

Answer (score 1):

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
$topicos = $_POST['campo'];
$query = "INSERT INTO reuniao (nm_reuniao,dt_reuniao,nm_criador,nm_topico) VALUES ('$nm_reuniao','$dt_reuniao', '$logado','$nm_topico')";
foreach ($topicos as $nm_topico) {
  $insert = mysql_query($query,$connect);
}
```

Sua variável `$nm_topico` recebe um array com as informações passadas pelo seu formulário com `name='campo[]'`, então para que seja inseridas todas as linhas é necessário fazer uma estrutura de repetição inserindo linha a linha.